# PL/SQL ORACLE query as Result

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to write SQL Query for below condition

Result must be in PL/SQL Query:

MY_TABLE  and data is Like bellow:

```
|   sl. no | col1 | col2 | col3 |col4    | col5 ---col30| col41|col42|....col50
+------   +------+------ +------ +------+
|    1001 |    50 |  101 |  12   |  40   |
|    1002 |    30 |  250 |  80   |       |
|    1003 |    40 |  150 |  90   |       |
|    1004 |    50 |  250 |  20   |       |
|    1005 |    70 |  300 |  30   | 50    |
|    1006 |    80 |  400 |
```

col1, col2,col3,...col30

I want to retrieve col1..to col30 data(value) against sl.no (where condition is sl.no) if col data is available. Oracle 9I 
as row wise 
only in PL/SQL oracle 9i
result like:

```
1001 | 50
1001 | 101
1001 | 12
1001 | 40
1002 | 30 
1002 |250
1002 | 80  
1003 | 40
1003 | 150
1003 | 90
1004 | 50
1004 | 250
1004 | 20 
1005 |70
1005 |300
1005 |30
1005 |50
1006 |80
1006 |400
```

Comment: You want to unpivot your table? Why do you want/have to use PL/SQL?

Comment: Thanks Aleksej for editing Question.

Comment: @Alex existing DB is Oracle 9i and Language is SQL

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: What is a "PL/SQL Query"?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (
  select no, decode( rn, 1, col1, 2, col2, 3, col3, 4, col4, 5, col5, ...., 30, col30) col
  from table_name, (select rownum rn from all_objects where rownum <= 30 )
) 
where col is not null
```

or

```
select * 
from (
  select no, decode( rn, 1, col1, 2, col2, 3, col3, 4, col4, 5, col5, ...., 30, col30) col
  from table_name, (select rownum rn from dual connect by rownum <= 30 )
) 
where col is not null
```

the second one is better but I don't remember will it works in 9i or not

Answer (score 0):

To unpivot the pre-11g way, you would need to do something like:

```
WITH my_table AS (SELECT 1001 sl_no, 50 col1, 101 col2, 12 col3, 40 col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1002 sl_no, 30 col1, 250 col2, 80 col3, NULL col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1003 sl_no, 40 col1, 150 col2, 90 col3, NULL col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1004 sl_no, 50 col1, 250 col2, 20 col3, NULL col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1005 sl_no, 70 col1, 300 col2, 30 col3, 50 col4 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1006 sl_no, 80 col1, 400 col2, NULL col3, NULL col4 FROM dual),
        dummy AS (SELECT LEVEL lvl
                  FROM   dual
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 -- number of columns to unpivot
                  ),
       results AS (SELECT mt.sl_no,
                          d.lvl,
                          CASE WHEN d.lvl = 1 THEN 'COL1'
                               WHEN d.lvl = 2 THEN 'COL2'
                               WHEN d.lvl = 3 THEN 'COL3'
                               WHEN d.lvl = 4 THEN 'COL4'
                          END col_name,
                          CASE WHEN d.lvl = 1 THEN col1
                               WHEN d.lvl = 2 THEN col2
                               WHEN d.lvl = 3 THEN col3
                               WHEN d.lvl = 4 THEN col4
                          END col_value
                   FROM   my_table mt
                          CROSS JOIN dummy d)
SELECT sl_no,
       col_name,
       col_value
FROM   results
WHERE  col_value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sl_no, lvl;

     SL_NO COL_NAME  COL_VALUE
---------- -------- ----------
      1001 COL1             50
      1001 COL2            101
      1001 COL3             12
      1001 COL4             40
      1002 COL1             30
      1002 COL2            250
      1002 COL3             80
      1003 COL1             40
      1003 COL2            150
      1003 COL3             90
      1004 COL1             50
      1004 COL2            250
      1004 COL3             20
      1005 COL1             70
      1005 COL2            300
      1005 COL3             30
      1005 COL4             50
      1006 COL1             80
      1006 COL2            400
```

The `dummy` subquery is used to generate a set of rows that is the same number as the number of columns to be unpivoted. In your example, it's 4.

We then cross join that to the table - this means each row in the table is duplicated 4 times - one for each column to be unpivoted.

Once we have that, we say "display the first column to be unpivoted on the first row, the second column on the second row, the third column on the third row, etc..."

I've also included a column which lists the column name that the corresponding value came from; I know you didn't ask for this info in your question, but it's usually required, and easy enough to produce.

Once we have unpivoted the columns, we then remove any values that are null.